# How can I define a regexp pattern as a constant in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, datetime

i want to define a regexp constant in my script at the top and use it later to check the date string's format.

my date string will be defined as

> $a="2013-03-20 11:09:30.788";

but it failed.
how should i do ?

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;


 use constant REGEXP1 => "/^\d{4}\D\d{2}\D\d{2}\D\d{2}\D\d{2}\D\d{2}\D\d{3}$/";

 $a="2013-03-20 11:09:30.788";
 if(not $a=~&REGEXP1){
         print "not"

 }else{
         print "yes"

 }
 print "\n";
```

Answer (score 8):

First, let's look at `"/^\d{4}\D\d{2}\D\d{2}\D\d{2}\D\d{2}\D\d{2}\D\d{3}$/";` If you had warnings on, you should have gotten:

```
Unrecognized escape \d passed through at C:\temp\jj.pl line 7.
Unrecognized escape \D passed through at C:\temp\jj.pl line 7.
Unrecognized escape \d passed through at C:\temp\jj.pl line 7.
…
```

If you print the value of `REGEXP1`, you will get `/^d{4}Dd{2}Dd{2}Dd{2}Dd{2}Dd{2}Dd{3}` (*wait, what happened to **`$/`**?). Clearly, that does not look like the pattern you wanted.

Now, you could type `"/^\\d{4}\\D\\d{2}\\D\\d{2}\\D\\d{2}\\D\\d{2}\\D\\d{2}\\D\\d{3}\$/"` and then interpolate that string into a pattern, but that's too much work. Instead, you can define your constant using the [regexp quote operator, `qr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.012;
use strict;
use warnings;

use constant REGEXP1 => qr/^\d{4}\D\d{2}\D\d{2}\D\d{2}\D\d{2}\D\d{2}\D\d{3}$/;

my $s = "2013-03-20 11:09:30.788";

say $s =~ REGEXP1 ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

There is one more gotcha: `\d` and `\D` will match more than just `[0-9]` and `[^0-9]`, respectively. So, instead, you could write your pattern like:

```
use constant REGEXP1 => qr{
    \A
    (?<year>  [0-9]{4} ) -
    (?<month> [0-9]{2} ) -
    (?<day>   [0-9]{2} ) [ ]
    (?<hour>  [0-9]{2} ) :
    (?<min>   [0-9]{2} ) :
    (?<sec>   [0-9]{2} ) [.]
    (?<msec>  [0-9]{3} )
    \z
}x;
```

But, you are still left with the question of whether those values are meaningful. If that matters, you can use [DateTime::Format::Strptime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DateTime%3a%3aFormat%3a%3aStrptime).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.012;
use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $s = "2013-03-20 11:09:30.788";

my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern => '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N',
    on_error => 'croak',
);

my $dt = $strp->parse_datetime($s);
say $strp->format_datetime($dt);
```

Comment: What do `\d` and `\D` match outside of `[0-9]`?

Comment: See "Digits" in [perldoc perlrecharclass](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html). *What this means is that unless the `/a` modifier is in effect `\d` not only matches the digits `'0' - '9'`, but also Arabic, Devanagari, and digits from other languages. This may cause some confusion, and some security issues.*

Answer (score 3):

Which version of Perl are you using? It works for me in 5.8.8 (but not 5.004) if you change it to this:

```
use constant REGEXP1 => qr/^\d{4}\D\d{2}\D\d{2}\D\d{2}\D\d{2}\D\d{2}\D\d{3}$/;
```